# Modify .htaccess for Codeigniter | Subdomain | Many sub folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

My query is as following:

On my server, I have multiple codeigniter apps in one folder and 1 subdomain pointing to that folder

Please see the following structure:

- eApps **(Main Folder)**

  - index.php (used to redirect to Main App) **File**
  - Main App (Used for redirecting to other apps) **(Sub Folder)**
  - Timekeeping App **(Sub Folder)**
  - Activity Delivery App **(Sub Folder)**
  - .....so on (15 Apps in total) **(Sub Folders)**

The main app redirects to other apps by having a common session. This is working perfectly fine on the local server
But on the live server (1and1.co.uk), it has the following problems:
This is due to improper (htaccess) I think:
[image: This is due to improper (htaccess) I think]

I don't know what htaccess files to keep in the main folder and what in each folders in order for this to work properly

Sometimes it gives 404 page not found error as well

This is the .htaccess in the main folder: 
[image: .htaccess]

Comment: Please do not include text as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have many app in one folder in my server and for all .htaccess file I use the following code which works fine for me.
Try replacing the following code in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|fevicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```